# Cannot make ajaxs call when deploy in heroku

Tags: ajax, node.js, reactjs, heroku, redux

I have an web app which I bundled using webpack, I placed my entire react/redux app in the public file which will be served by nodejs(express-generator). My app works when I run in localhost/ local env. However when I deploy to heroku. I cannot make calls.

The below is the error message:

```
    bundle.js:19 GET https://glacial-cove-64389.herokuapp.com/users/ 401 (Unauthorized)

Object {err: Error: Request failed with status code 401 at e.exports (https://glacial-cove-64389.herokuapp.co…}
err
:
Error: Request failed with status code 401 at e.exports (https://glacial-cove-64389.herokuapp.com/bundle.js:19:10382) at e.exports (https://glacial-cove-64389.herokuapp.com/bundle.js:26:6821) at XMLHttpRequest._.(anonymous function) (https://glacial-cove-64389.herokuapp.com/bundle.js:19:9464)
__proto__
:
Object
```

initially I thought it could be my my ROOT_URL so I changed it the below is an example of my actions file.

```
const ROOT_URL = "//glacial-cove-64389.herokuapp.com"
const axiosOption = {headers: { authorization : localStorage.getItem('token')}}

/*Sign in user*/
export function signinUser({ email, password }){
  return function(dispatch){
    axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/users/signin`, { email, password })
    .then(function(res){
      dispatch({ type: AUTH_USER })
      localStorage.setItem('token', res.data.token);
      browserHistory.push('/users');
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      dispatch(authError('Invalid email or password'))
      console.log({err});
    })
  }
}
```

So what happens is that the react recognize the login and push user to the correct route. but it return the above error msg status code 401 once it hits the main pages.

The main problem I have is when I try to perform CRUD which doesn't work

Here is my repo: https://github.com/boyboi86/API_basic_random

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the hard way..

If you intend to put everything within your public file when scaffold with express-generator. Putting CORS within your Nodejs is insufficient because now your axios (react) that makes the call is also subjected to CORS, And you will have to config within your axios with the following:

```
axios.defaults.headers.post['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'PATCH, DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS';
```

This is to ensure all calls made will be allowed. I realised this when I look at the response headers.